# post thumbnails error

Tags: posts, post-thumbnails

i want to make a wp theme myself
almost i do it but there is a biiiig problem and i cant solve it
i had add add_theme_support to function 
and add the post thumbnail in my index
but still cant give the posts , featured image.
if i apply another theme i can set featured image but on my own damn theme no !
also when i add featured image on another theme to my post , i can see that image when my theme is applied
but still cant edit or delet that !!!
and i check all over the edit-post page 
and there is no featured image option to check that damn box

please help me ❤

Answer (score 0):

Are you added `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );` line into functions.php file of your theme?

Also check the loop. Are you added `the_post_thumbnail()` function there?